# Square every digit of a number

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn JavaScript but find it to be a bit confusing. I am trying to square every digit of a number

For example: run 9119 through the function, 811181 will come out, because 9^2 is 81 and 1^2 is 1.

My code:

```
function squareDigits(num){
    return Math.pow(num[0],2) && Math.pow(num[1],2);
}
```

Correct code:

```
function squareDigits(num){
    return Number(('' + num).split('').map(function (val) { return val * val;}).join(''));
}
```

I do not know why `.map`, `.split`, and `.join` was used to answer the question.

Comment: Splitting the number allows us to use the map function to apply a function to all of these elements we just split. The function we choose is to square it. We join all these elements back together so that it is returned as a single string.

Comment: Do as all of us need to, learn to read the docs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.split` takes a string and splits it into an array based on the character(s) passed to it `''` in this case.

So

```
("9119").split('') === ["9", "1", "1", "9"]
```

`.map` works like a for loop but takes a function as an argument.  That function is applied to every member of the array.

So

```
["9", "1", "1", "9"].map(function(val) { return val * val;}) === ["81", "1", "1", "81"]
```

`.join` does the opposite of `.split`.  It takes an Array and concatenates it into a string based on the character(s) passed to it.

So

```
["81", "1", "1", "81"].join('') === "811181"
```

Additionally, the `&&` operator checks to see if the expressions on either side of it evaluate to true.  If both expressions evaluate to true, only then will it return true.  It always returns a Boolean though.  I think you wanted to convert your values to string first using `Number.toString()` and then append them together using the `+` operator

```
return Math.pow(num[0],2).toString() + Math.pow(num[1],2).toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

function squareDigits(num) {

```
// Convert the result to a number. "252525" -> 252525
return Number( 
                num.toString() // num === "555"

                .split('') // ["5", "5", "5"]

                .map(elem => elem * elem) "5" * "5" === 25 (Type coversion)
                // Now we have [25, 25, 25]

                .join('') // "252525"
            );
```

}

squareDigits(555);

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need single digits for getting squared values.

You could take [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), which splits a string (which is a type with an implemented [`Symbol.iterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator)) into characters and uses an optional maping for the values.

```js
function sqare(number) {
    return +Array.from(number.toString(), v => v * v).join('');
}

console.log(sqare(9119));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods of this, but the first that comes to mind is to pass the number as a string, split it, then parse the numbers, square them individually, make them strings, and paste them back together, it sounds complex but makes sense once you see it

```
//function takes number as an argument
function convertNumber(num){
   //the toString method converts a number into a string
   var number = num.toString();
   //the split method splits the string into individual numbers
   var arr = number.split("");
   //this variable will hold the numbers that we square later
   var squaredArr = [];
   //the for loop iterates through everything in our array
   for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
      //parseInt turns a string into a number
      var int = parseInt(arr[i]);
      //Math.pow raises integers to a given exponent, in this case 2
      int = Math.pow(int, 2);
      //we push the number we just made into our squared array as a string
      squaredArr.push(int.toString());
   }
   //the function returns the numbers in the squared array after joining 
   //them together.  You could also parseInt the array if you wanted, doing 
   //this as parseInt(squaredArr[0]);  (this would be done after joining)
   return squaredArr.join('');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try these code..

```js
function squareDigits(n) {
    return +(n.toString().split('').map(val => val * val).join(''));
}
console.log(squareDigits(4444));
```

here + sign is convert the string into an integer.

Comment: Please read the question content before replying. The author was confused about why these 3 specific method where used.

Comment: ok bro I'm sorry. I am just trying to give an honest answer.